# Combine image assets widths to get total width

Tags: assets, image-transforms, image

How can I check if multiple asset image widths combined are wider than X?
So how do i get X?

Like this:

File 1 = 300px wide
File 2 = 200px wide
File 3 = 250px wide

```
x >= 750px than<br />
  Do This<br /><br />
else<br />
  Do that<br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
{% set totalWidth = 0 %}

{% for asset in myAssetList %}
    {% set totalWidth = totalWidth + asset.width %}
{% endfor %}

{% if totalWidth > 750 %}
    Do this.
{% else %}
    Do that.
{% endif %}
```